# Как получить последнее сообщение с возможностью управлять им? Discord.net c#

Tags: c#, discord

Как получить последнее сообщение таким образом, чтобы я мог управлять им, а конкретно удалить? `msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(число сообщений)` Не подходит, так как таким образом я не могу удалить полученные сообщения. Пробовал преобразовывать все это с помощью `as`, но выдает ошибку, что оно не указывает на объект.

Comment: Опять на теж грабли. 1. Если не так задали вопрос, то отредактируйте старый, нажмите кнопку переоткрыть, его откроют. 2. `не могу удалить полученные сообщения` - где ваши попытки? Я вот до сих пор не вижу ни единой строчки кода. Сейчас я лично думаю, что вы работаете с коллекцией как с одним объектом, а должны проходиться циклом, удаляя поочередно каждое сообщение. Так что, пожалуйста, не описывайте код словами, дайте нам этот код, ваши попытки, тогда и будет уже что либо думать.

Comment: 1. Если тебе не нравится мой вопрос, не надо отвечать.

Comment: 2. Я по разному пробовал, и foreach и for, выдает одну и туже ошибку.

Comment: 3. Мне нужен ответ хотя бы можно ли как-то по другому это сделать. Если вариантов нет, я постараюсь разобраться.

Comment: 4. Я бы с радостью предоставил вам код, но все что я пытаюсь пока сделать выдает ошибку еще до компиляции, основная причина это отсутствие GetEnumerator.
Если у меня получается запустить код, то он как-будто не видит сообщение нужное мне сообщение.

Comment: Язвить не надо, вас вроде вежливо попросили "Дайте код, который не работает", вы начинаете хамить. Я чтоль виноват, что вы задали вопрос на английском, дождались его закрытия (проигнорировав мое сообщение про то, что тут такое закрывают), потом создали дубликат вместо исправления прошлого? Да вроде нет. К чему тогда притензии ко мне я не пойму? Еще раз повторю, дайте тот код, который не работает, будем разбираться, иначе смысл тогда вашего вопроса в чем? Я вам сказал, как получать сообщения - `.GetMessagesAsync()`, но пишете "не подходит, нельзя удалить", а то, что это единственный вариант?

Comment: Если я вас оскорбил, я прошу прощения. Про первый вопрос, я не заметил что меня перекинуло на русскую версию сайта, а переоткрыть не получилось. А на счет кода который не работает, я его удалил, но вот код который примерно такой же.
```var messages = msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(10) as IEnumerable<IMessage>;
                    foreach (var del_msg in messages)
                    {
                        await del_msg.DeleteAsync();
                    }```
Он выдает ошибку - System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: Воот, уже вместо язвительного тона, появилась хоть какая-либо информация, с которой можно работать. `GetMessagesAsync(10)` - это асинхронный метод, где `await`?  Также `as IEnumerable<IMessage>;`, ибо это, по сути, и так коллекция. Также может пригодиться `.FlattenAsync()` после `GetMessagesAsync()`, из асинхронной коллекции сделает вам полноценную коллекцию для работы. Ну а также, учтите, дискорд имеет лимит на разовое удаление сообщений, если у вас их много, то лучше использовать метод `.DeleteMessagesAsync()` канала, но и он имеет ограничения - удаляет только новые сообщения, старые нельзя.

Comment: Если вы про ```await``` перед ```foreach```, то с этим так же есть проблема. Если я ставлю его перед `ё`foreach```, появляется ошибка, что это не доступно в версии c# 7.3, только в 8.0 и выше, а как изменить версию я не нашел.
А при удалении ```as IEnumerable<IMessage>;``` редактор ругается на то, что в переменной ```messages``` нет определения или расширения для GetEnumerator.

Comment: Почему перед `foreach` то `var messages = await msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(10); //.FlattenAsync() если надо еще в конце.`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. ```var messages = await msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(10);``` помогло.

Comment: На будущее, поймите, вам тут не обязан кто либо, наоборот, это в ваших интересах доставить до нас, незнакомцев всю нужную информацию, все попытки (даже если они неудачны). Ведь если я бы не был таким настойчивым, прошел мимо (как вы советовали), то другие точно не стали бы возиться (дискорд метка не очень популярна тут), а опять закрыли вопрос. Не игнорируйте комментарии, не воспринимайте их в штыки, следуйте советам, просьбам, да и правилам ресурса. Удачи!

Comment: Обязательно учту все это. И вам удачи!